# Optimising query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, query-optimization

This view query is taking 2min to load 500 000 lines.
I'm using EF 4.0 and thread load this view on a DataGrid.
How can I optimize it so it can load in shorter time ?

**Update** : I updated the query to this and now it takes 55 seconds but still too long !

```
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY ss.IDStore_CardStore DESC ) AS Id_PK ,
        SC.IDStockCardIndex ,
        SC.Designation ,
        ISNULL(P.PMP, 0) PMP ,
        ISNULL(SS.Quantity, 0) Quantity ,
        SS.UnitePrice * SS.Quantity AS SubTotalStockCard ,
        S.StoreName ,
        SS.IDPurchaseInvoice
FROM    dbo.Stores S
        INNER JOIN dbo.StockCardsStores ss ON S.IDStore = ss.IDStore
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.StockCard SC ON ss.IDStockCardIndex = SC.IDStockCardIndex
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ( SELECT    SUM(UnitePrice * Quantity) / SUM(Quantity) AS PMP ,
                                    IDStockCardIndex
                          FROM      dbo.StockCardsStores AS SCS
                          GROUP BY  IDStockCardIndex
                        ) AS P ON P.IDStockCardIndex = SC.IDStockCardIndex
```

Comment: MIght want to make the code easier to decipher if you state what it's trying to achieve and also maybe using correlation names to make it a lot lot shorter. Also `NULLIF(dbo.StockCard.IDStockCardIndex, NEWID())' can be replaced with  `dbo.StockCard.IDStockCardIndex`

Comment: I used NULLIF() on purpose of getting a one column primary key at Entity Model

Comment: Are you using paging for your DataGrid?

Comment: I'm kind of surprised it finishes in 2 minutes.  You have a LOT going on it that query.  I highly suggest this gets moved to dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: How long is the raw query versus the load to the DataGrid.  If you don't need edit go Listview Gridview as it is much faster than DataGrid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Estimate Execution Plan in SSMS. If you're using 2008 R2, SSMS will suggest "missing index" that will possibly improve the time overall. 500,000 rows at 55 seconds suggest that one or more table scans are kicking in. The Estimated Execution Plan will identify these. The Plan will also show what part of the query "costs" the most overall, helping you to zero in.

Highlight that inner sub-query and look at the plan for that first. Then work your way outwards.

Comment: Thanks @Scott L Holmes I got it excuting in almost 8 seconds, I needs more optimization doesn't it ?

Comment: At this point, the next thing I would do would be to experiment with Common Table Expressions or think of a better way to join. With complicated queries like this, I tend to have inner queries that focus on getting at the keys, then outer queries that look up/calculate the real attributes I'm interested in.